# how to implement cost sensitive learning for logistic regression in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I have a data set which is highly imbalanced. majority to minority class ratio is 99:1. I would like to build a model which should predict the minority class accurately. In simple terms i want to perform cost sensitive learning in which cost of false negative should be higher than cost of false positive. 
But i didn't find any package in R for logistic regression which will do the same.

Can any body recommend some document of site having example of R code to do the same.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are willing to accept increase in false positives (as it appears you are) then you simply need to change the prediction threshold. No need for extra packages.

Comment: that's fine. currently i am doing same as you told. But i want model to learn based on cost. there should be some penalty associated with classifying minority class wrong . I hope you get the question . Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any algorithm that does not offer a cost option, you can just oversample the minority class. For example, if you want to weight them 5x then just oversample them by a factor of 5.

There is a lot of literature out there for how to deal with imbalanced data. General approaches include oversampling the minority class or undersampling the majority class. Additionally, you can get into more advanced techniques such as SMOTE, which will create synthetic observations based on your minority class.

In cases with high imbalances such as yours, I've found that a combination of oversampling the majority and undersampling the minority many times so that you get multiple models that you can average together produces good results. (Basically, this is modified bagging)

Comment: Thank you. I will do the same.

Comment: Glad to help! If you feel this answered your question, please mark this as correct.